# In-Line Assembler for use with Common Language Runtime Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, forms, c++-cli, clr

Edit: Lots of users have recommended me to notes for C#. But, this is CPP common language runtime. And I am using forms, so whoever says that this has nothing to do with forms is wrong.

[image: Here is the screnshot showing you what I'm doing with CPP and forms]
[image: Here is how I built the CPP project (NOT C#)]
[image: Here's how I added the form to my CPP project]

So, again, I'm looking for in-line assembler with common language runtime (CLR), using C++, not C#.

I'm trying to replicate a program from my textbook. It's been painstakingly hard, and now I've met another obstacle which is not covered in the book: the CLR doesn't seem to like my in-line assembler. Something to do with managed vs. unmanaged memory. I don't know, I'm a little over my head. I wanted to just be able to run the program to replciate this silly example in my book, but I've spent hours trying to iron out all the kinks. Thanks in advance. Also, please refrain from any advice regarding how I should be using C# for this. The class is dated and I can't do anything about this. I'm an EE major and I have only taken two programming classes before this. Thx.

Here's the textbook program snips:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Ejk.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGTnY.jpg

```
namespace Ch8P19 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;





    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

//#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(80, 72);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            this->textBox1->KeyDown += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventHandler(this, &MyForm::textbox1_KeyDown);
            this->textBox1->KeyPress += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventHandler(this, &MyForm::textbox1_KeyPress);
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(80, 144);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 22);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(8, 16);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(282, 253);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::formload);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }

//#pragma endregion








            //EXAMPLE 8–15

        int Filter(char key)
        {
            int retval;
            _asm
            {
                mov eax, 1
                cmp key, 8; backspace
                je good
                cmp key, 30h
                jb bad
                cmp key, 39h
                jbe good
                cmp key, 41h
                jb bad
                cmp key, 46h
                jbe good
                cmp key, 61h
                jb bad
                cmp key, 66h
                jbe good
                good : dec al
                bad : mov retval, eax
            }
            return retval;
        }

        int Converts(int number, short digit)
        {
            _asm
            {
                mov eax, number
                shl eax, 4
                mov dx, digit
                sub dx, 30h
                cmp dx, 9
                jbe later
                sub dx, 7
                later: or al, dl
                mov number, eax
            }
            return number;
        }



    private: System::Void formload(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
    {
        textBox1->Focus(); // set Focus to textbox1
    }
             bool keyHandled;

    private: System::Void textbox1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
    {

        keyHandled = Filter(e->KeyValue);
    }

    private: System::Void textbox1_KeyPress(System::Object^  sender,
        System::Windows::Forms::KeyPressEventArgs^  e)
    {
        if (e->KeyChar >= 'a' && e->KeyChar <= 'f')
        {
            e->KeyChar -= 32;
        }
        else if (e->KeyChar == 13)
        {
            int number = 0;
            for (int a = 0; a < textBox1->Text->Length; a++)
            {
                number = Converts(number, textBox1->Text[a]);
            }
            textBox2->Text = Convert::ToString(number);
            keyHandled = true;
        }
        e->Handled = keyHandled;
    }



    };



}
```

ERRORS:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Ch8P19, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>MyForm.cpp
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(148): error C3644: 'Ch8P19::MyForm::Filter': cannot compile the function to generate managed code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(148): note: Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(169): error C3821: 'int Ch8P19::MyForm::Filter(char)': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(169): note: Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(145): error C3645: 'Ch8P19::MyForm::Filter': __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(173): error C3644: 'Ch8P19::MyForm::Converts': cannot compile the function to generate managed code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(173): note: Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(186): error C3821: 'int Ch8P19::MyForm::Converts(int,short)': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(186): note: Inline native assembly not supported in managed code
1>c:\users\trent\source\repos\ch8p19\ch8p19\myform.h(171): error C3645: 'Ch8P19::MyForm::Converts': __clrcall cannot be used on functions compiled to native code
1>Done building project "Ch8P19.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Put `#pragma managed(push, off)` before the function and `#pragma managed(pop)` after it.